# Pixel-wise multivariable regression to estimate solar irradiance from Worldclim data

Tags: raster, r, layers, climate, regression

I want to do a pixel-wise multivariable regression to predict missing "srad13" and "srad14" data where "srad" is the dependent variable using the independent variable tmin01 + tmin02 + tmin13 + tmin14 + tmax01 + tmax02 + tmax13 + tmax14 + prec01 + prec02 + prec13 + prec14 and the two already given "srad01" and "srad02".

```
# Extract independent variable values and create data frame
coord_srad01 <- coordinates(srad01)
coord_srad02 <- coordinates(srad02)
xy <- cbind(coord_srad01[,1], coord_srad01[,2], coord_srad02[,1], coord_srad02[,2])
ind_vars_vals <- extract(ind_vars, xy)
train_data <- data.frame(ind_vars = ind_vars_vals, srad = c(values(srad01), values(srad02)))
```

I get the following error when I do train_data

```
Error in .xyValues(x, y, method = method, buffer = buffer, small = small,  : 
  xy should have 2 columns only.
Found these dimensions: 895622, 4
```

Further, I would like to do something like this to do a regression

```
# Create a function for the regression model
model_fun <- function(x) lm(srad ~ ., data = x)

# Apply the model to predict srad13 and srad14 at missing locations
srad13 <- predict(raster(ind_vars, template = srad01, varname = "srad13"), train_data, model_fun)
srad14 <- predict(raster(ind_vars, template = srad01, varname = "srad14"), train_data, model_fun)

# Save the predicted data as TIFF files
writeRaster(srad13, "path/to/srad13.tif", overwrite = TRUE)
writeRaster(srad14, "path/to/srad14.tif", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please use code blocks to distinguish code from question body and error messages.

Comment: yeah, sorry for that. hope it is better now :)

Comment: Your error is coming from one line that doesn't need anything else in the question to show the problem. You can tidy this up and encourage more people to read and answer it by making it as minimal as necessary. I nearly skipped it.

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from this one line:

```
r <- raster(extent(xmin = -180, xmax = 180, ymin = -90, ymax = 90), ncol = 360, nrow = 180)
```

which gives me the error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'raster': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extent’ for signature ‘"missing"’
```

So let's break this down. Is the internal call to `extent` working?

```
> extent(xmin = -180, xmax = 180, ymin = -90, ymax = 90)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extent’ for signature ‘"missing"’
```

No, okay, how does `extent` work? Read the help:

```
 This function returns an Extent object of a Raster* or Spatial*
 object (or an Extent object), or creates an Extent object from a
 2x2 matrix (first row: xmin, xmax; second row: ymin, ymax), vector
 (length=4; order= xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) or list (with at least
 two elements, with names 'x' and 'y')
```

Although its not totally explicit, you don't name the arguments, they have to be in the order specified. You can see this in the examples:

```
  extent(0, 20, 0, 20)
```

So remove the naming of the parameters and this works:

```
> r <- raster(extent( -180, 180, -90, 90), ncol = 360, nrow = 180)
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 180, 360, 64800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your response: now this runs but in the next line I get the following error:
´´´
solar_pred <- predict(model, newdata = predict_years, type = "response")
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'min_temp' not found
´´´

Comment: We can't fix all your errors in one question - the format here is for minimally short questions with good single answers. This way if anyone else has the same problem then they can find the help quickly and easily, for example by searching for the error message.

Comment: Maybe it is clearer now and somebody is able to help without reading through the whole info about the dataset.

Comment: Yes but now this answer has **no** relation to your question since you edited it. You should have edited your Q to say only "When I do this [raster/extent code] I get this error.", then my answer fixes that. Then you start a new Q saying "When I do this [train data line] I get this error" and someone can answer *that* specific problem. Please don't move the goalposts once you've got an answer.